# How to avoid real numbers conversions in mjson.tool

Tags: python, json

I have discovered that mjson.tool converts real number using scientific notation, e.g:

```
$ echo '{"k":0.000000581}' | python -mjson.tool
{
    "k": 5.81e-07
}
```

However, I would like to avoid this conversion, so the former get printed as:

```
{
    "k": 0.000000581
}
```

It is possible to use mjson.tool in such way, please?

Comment: @soon, you are right... I have fixed my post (surprisingly, mjson.tool didn't complaint :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, mjson module just convert the input to json and back to string with indentation and sorted keys.

This can be done with:

```
>>> json.dumps(json.loads('{"k":0.000000581}', indent=2, sort_keys=True))
'{"k": 5.81e-07}'
```

To avoid the scientifique notation, see @Veedrac answer on the subject:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936966/956660

---

**Edit**: Any tools that only reformat and does not try to parse/cast types will work.

I tried with [`yajl-tools`](https://lloyd.github.io/yajl/):

```
user$ sudo apt-get install yajl-tools
user$ echo '{"a": 0.0000000000000001337}' | json_pp 
{
   "a" : 1.337e-16
}
user$ echo '{"a": 0.0000000000000001337}' | json_reformat
{
    "a": 0.0000000000000001337
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to solve the problem at "shell space" (maybe some parameter to the mjson.tool invocation?) but in the case it isn't possible your feedback for a "Python space" solution is very valuable.